# OS X Installation Error

Tags: python, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install ROS on OS X Lion. I've used ROS a lot in Linux but would like to be able to run ros distributed onto a Mac. I am getting stuck on step 1.6 with a "python-svn could not be imported" error. I have already attempted to install python-svn using pip, homebrew as well as an independent package I found online. Not sure what to do.

**rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.30', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 781, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 703, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 234, in __init__
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 283, in load_yaml
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 223, in __init__
    
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/vcstools/vcs_abstraction.py", line 51, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/vcstools/svn.py", line 66, in __init__
vcstools.vcs_base.VcsError: 'python-svn could not be imported. Please install python-svn. On debian systems sudo apt-get install python-svn'
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28124/os-x-installation-error/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually we moved back from pysvn as the dependencies seem to cause problems and due to licensing issues. So after an update of rosinstall and vcstools, this should be fine again.
Note that easy_install does not update vcstools if you just tell it to update rosinstall. use pip or tell easy_install to also update vcstools.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vcstools now requires pysvn, and it is not in pypi yet.  I made a Homebrew formula for it here:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/10570

I would recommend not using Homebrew's Python, but just use Apple's.

You can use my formula in the mean time, while it is getting put into Homebrew, by running these commands:

```
brew pull 10570
brew install pysvn
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2012-02-28**:
Thanks again, but that isn't working either. Comment on github.com...

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-02-29**:
I can confirm this works against the system Python using the pull request.